# C# JObject Unexpected token when deserializing multidimensional array

Tags: c#

I am using JObject to read various api responses. With the following json

```
{"API":{"Year":["2020","2019","2018","2017","2016","2015"],

 "Status": {"Message":"The call returned successfully with years"}}}
```

I can use this:

```
 dynamic json= JObject.Parse(s);
            string[] yrs = json.API.Year.ToObject<string[]>();
```

where s is the json object.
This works perfectly to give me a simple array of years.
I am having difficulty parsing multi dimensions in the json response. when i have the following:

```
{"API":{"Category":[

{"GroupName":"Exterior Accessories","GroupID":"2",
    "Items":
        [{"Id":"64","Value":"Body Part"},
        {"Id":"20","Value":"Body Styling"},
        {"Id":"7","Value":"Bras and Hood Protectors"}]
},

{"GroupName":"Interior Accessories","GroupID":"4",

    "Items":
        [{"Id":"21","Value":"Carpet",
        {"Id":"2","Value":"Doors and Components"},
        {"Id":"8","Value":"Floor Protection"}]
},

], 

"Status": {"Message":"The call (api.v12.estore.catalograck.com) returned successfully with categories.","DataFound":true,"TimeStamp":"02/02/2020 11:48:27","InternalError":false}}}
```

How can I parse this into a multi-dimensional array?

Comment: Can you add some C# code showing how you expected it to work?

Comment: What do you mean by multi dimensions in the json ?

Comment: I was trying to use a double[][] or double[,] like json.API.Year.ToObject<double[][]>(); My mistake, I now understand I need to use classes as specified in the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Since Years you used was a simple built in element (string), you dont need to create any classes.. but the Categories you have in your JSON is a object. To access the Categories in a way you can access its elements, I would recommend creating the necessary classes and then using the Category list of the root object to do what you need.

Example code

```
public class Item
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public string GroupID { get; set; }
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Status
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public bool DataFound { get; set; }
    public string TimeStamp { get; set; }
    public bool InternalError { get; set; }
}

public class API
{
    public List<Category> Category { get; set; }
    public Status Status { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public API API { get; set; }
}
```

Above are the needed classes for succesful deserialization where RootObject class is the parent.

Use the following in your Main method.,

```
RootObject root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
List<Category> categories = root.API.Category;
```